# Dificuldade em criar uma property para uma CLASSE

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Estou usando o DELPHI 7 tentando criar uma classe com a seguinte estrutura

```
Type
  Tclasse_Envio_JSON =  class(TThread)
  private  
    fCampos: Array of Variant;
    fIdade : Integer;
    fNome  : String[40];
    function Get_Idade: Integer;
    procedure Set_Idade(const Value: Integer);    
    function Get_Campos: array of Variant;
    procedure Set_Campos(const Value: array of Variant);         
  public
    Property Idade : Integer read Get_Idade write Set_Idade;    
    Property Campos : Array of Variant read Get_Campos write Set_Campos;
  protected
    procedure Execute; Override;      
end;
```

Estou tendo dificuldades em implementar a:

```
property Campos
function Get_Campos 
procedure Set_Campos
```

A ideia de sua utilização seria

```
variavelA       := TClasse_Envio_JSon.Create;
VariavelA.Campo := ['CampoA','CampoB','CampoC'];
VariavelA.Valor :=['Valor_CampoA','Valor_CampoB','Valor_CampoC'];
```

Como devo Usar o **ARRAY Of VARIANT** nessa situação???
Ou Caso algum dos senhores tenha uma outra ideia que eu possa obter o mesmo resultado.. sou todo OLHOS :) 
Poderia Fazer algo com STRINGS delimitadas e fazer a busca nelas, mas o lance
com Array of Variant é bem mais limpo.
Nos usamos muito Array of Variante na passagem de parametros em funçôes.
Inclusive Esta classe que estou querendo implementar é para subistituir uma função.

```
Function Envia_Json(pCampos : Array of Variant; pValores : Array of Variant) : Boolean;
Var A : Integer;
begin
  For A:= 0 to High(pCampos) do
      begin
         ETC..ETC..
      end;
  ETC.. ETC..
end;
```

Usando a Function Envia_Json..:

```
  If Envia_Json(['CampoA','CampoB'],['ValorAA','VAlorA','ValorB','ValorC','Valord']) then
     begin
     end;
```

Espero ter demonstrado minha duvida e necessidade claramente..
Caso algum dos senhores ache confuso minhas linhas, por favor me escreva que tentarei explicar melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Eu já penso em algo mais simples para resolver, tanto no envio quanto no recebimento...

Para envio imagine uma Lista (pode ser um TStringList), chave e valor...

Para receber utilizaria:

```
var
  vJson : TJSONObject;
begin
  vJson := TJSONObject.Create;  

  for i := 0 to Pred(xList.Count) do
  begin
    vJson.AddPair(xListaCHAVE, xListaVALOR);
  end;

  Result := vJson.ToString;
  vJson.Free;
end;
```

Obs: Para o `TJSONObject` declare `Data.DBXJSON` para versões antigas, para as novas utilise `System.Json`

Comment: Bom dia @Junior Moreira. Primeiro quero agradecer sua atenção :).  Algumas observações. Me corrija se estiver errado ok??  Pred(varTstringList)  isso funciona ou tu escreveu errado???  DATA.DBXJSON  eu tentei no delphi 7 e não encontrei isso.. Acho que o delphi 7 é mais antigo que o JSON correto??  Eu ate posso passar como StringList..mas isso acarreta em ter que criar variaveis StringList antes de usar a classe... se não houver outra solução .. vai ser essa mesmo :) abraços :)

Comment: ` Pred(varX.Count)` é igual a `varX.Count -1`, sobre a  DATA.DBXJSON, acredito que realmente ela possa não existir para esta versão, mas procure no github sobre `superobject` uma classe gigante que possui o JSON.

Comment: Moreira BRIGADUUU :)